# Will using DNS failover work as a Multi-DC failover strategy?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver

If I have a multi-DC cluster, ***DC1*** and ***DC2***, where DC2 is only used for failover. And in the driver on the client side, I define the contact points using the domain names `(foo1.net, foo2.net, and foo3.net)`. I have foo* pointing to DC1 and if I ever detect any error with DC1, I will make the DNS route foo* to point to DC2.

This approach seems to work on paper, but will it actually work? Any issues with this approach?

Answer (score 2):

In the case of the DataStax Java Driver 3.x this will not work since DNS is only evaluated at the beginning of `Cluster` instantiation.

The contact points provided are resolved using DNS via [InetAddress.getAllByName](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getAllByName-java.lang.String-) in [`Cluster.Builder.addContactPoint`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.5/com/datastax/driver/core/Cluster.Builder.html#addContactPoint-java.lang.String-):

```java
public Builder addContactPoint(String address) {
    // We explicitly check for nulls because InetAdress.getByName() will happily
    // accept it and use localhost (while a null here almost likely mean a user error,
    // not "connect to localhost")
    if (address == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();

    try {
        addContactPoints(InetAddress.getAllByName(address));
        return this;
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed to add contact point: " + address, e);
    }
}
```

If DNS is changed during the lifecycle of the `Cluster`, the driver will not be aware of this unless you construct a new `Cluster.Builder` instance and create a new `Cluster` from it.

I prefer a design that pushes Data Center failover outside the scope of your application and into a higher level of your architecture.  Instead of making your client application responsible for failing over, you should run instances of your clients colocated in each C* data center.  Your application load balancer/router/DNS could direct traffic to instances of your application in other data centers when data centers become unavailable.